# lightning multiselect dropdown showing options in a single row only

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have to use multiselect dropdown in lightning which should show options like : [image]

But its showing  options in a single line.

How to show all options in multiselect

```
  <ui:inputSelect multiple="true">
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="All Primary" label="All Contacts"/>
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="All Primary" label="All Primary"/>
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="All Secondary" label="All Secondary"/>

    </ui:inputSelect>
            <br/>

    <ui:inputSelect>

                <ui:inputSelectOption text="Any"  value="true1"/>
                <ui:inputSelectOption text="Open" value="true2"/>
                <ui:inputSelectOption text="Closed"  value="true3"/>
                <ui:inputSelectOption text="Closed Won"  value="true4"/>

        </ui:inputSelect>
```

Comment: Increase the height of the component using CSS and add slds-scrollable--y styleclass to the component.

Comment: **Use Control button to select multiple option**

Comment: @Bala Thnx.. its working

Comment: mind posting the snippet please? I am on the same boat, but not able to catch the hint :-(